# "Failed to create safeguard location for file" when loading Binary Data with "Allows External Storage" from CoreData with CloudKit after fresh install

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

**Background:** I have a Core Data model that uses CloudKit where I store images as "Binary Data" with "Allows External Storage" enabled. This works fine, *but*:

**Problem:** After a fresh install (meaning I deleted the app and optionally restarted the device, but didn't wipe the device itself) on my physical device, when the app starts, it loads ~150 of these images from iCloud and starts logging the following error for each:

> Note: I formatted the output and replaced the UUIDs with `<AppUUID>`, `<UUID2>` and `<UUID3>` to improve readability. The untouched output is below.
>
> `Receipts` is the name of the Core Data Entity that contains the `image` field.

```
open on /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/tmp/.LINKS/<UUID1>/<UUID2>_0x283d218b0: 
  No such file or directory

[error] error: Failed to create safeguard location for file: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/<UUID2> 
  error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “<UUID2>” doesn’t exist." 
UserInfo={
  NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/<UUID2>, 
  NSUserStringVariant=(Copy), 
  NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/tmp/.LINKS/<UUID1>/<UUID2>_0x283d218b0, 
  NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/<UUID2>, 
  NSUnderlyingError=0x28114f810 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}
}
```

and for some, but *other* images/UUIDs:

```
open on /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/tmp/.LINKS/<UUID1>/<UUID3>_0x283df45f0: 
  No such file or directory

[error] error: Failed to clone external data reference from /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/<UUID3>.interim 
  to /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/tmp/.LINKS/<UUID1>/<UUID3>_0x283df45f0 
  error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “<UUID3>.interim” doesn’t exist."
UserInfo={
  NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/<UUID3>.interim, 
  NSUserStringVariant=(Copy), 
  NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/tmp/.LINKS/<UUID1>/<UUID3>_0x283df45f0, 
  NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<AppUUID>/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/<UUID3>.interim, 
  NSUnderlyingError=0x2810a86f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}
}
```

*unedited log output:*

```
open on /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/tmp/.LINKS/DC56F37B-5992-4D6F-A789-05225C4B4399/99E2DEBB-8C99-4C2A-B962-4B26D87B8B6A_0x283d218b0: No such file or directory
[error] error: Failed to create safeguard location for file: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/99E2DEBB-8C99-4C2A-B962-4B26D87B8B6A error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “99E2DEBB-8C99-4C2A-B962-4B26D87B8B6A” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/99E2DEBB-8C99-4C2A-B962-4B26D87B8B6A, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/tmp/.LINKS/DC56F37B-5992-4D6F-A789-05225C4B4399/99E2DEBB-8C99-4C2A-B962-4B26D87B8B6A_0x283d218b0, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/99E2DEBB-8C99-4C2A-B962-4B26D87B8B6A, NSUnderlyingError=0x28114f810 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

open on /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/tmp/.LINKS/DC56F37B-5992-4D6F-A789-05225C4B4399/8C84C01C-EA5E-4DBF-A94E-0DFC1844BFE1_0x283df45f0: No such file or directory
[error] error: Failed to clone external data reference from /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/8C84C01C-EA5E-4DBF-A94E-0DFC1844BFE1.interim to /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/tmp/.LINKS/DC56F37B-5992-4D6F-A789-05225C4B4399/8C84C01C-EA5E-4DBF-A94E-0DFC1844BFE1_0x283df45f0 error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “8C84C01C-EA5E-4DBF-A94E-0DFC1844BFE1.interim” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/8C84C01C-EA5E-4DBF-A94E-0DFC1844BFE1.interim, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/tmp/.LINKS/DC56F37B-5992-4D6F-A789-05225C4B4399/8C84C01C-EA5E-4DBF-A94E-0DFC1844BFE1_0x283df45f0, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDBF2ECB-ECBA-4E6B-BF4E-48C91E2A0A61/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/8C84C01C-EA5E-4DBF-A94E-0DFC1844BFE1.interim, NSUnderlyingError=0x2810a86f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

---

**My interpretation:** Core Data tried to copy the downloaded, external file from `/Library/Application Support/.Receipts_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/<UUID2>` to `/tmp/.LINKS/<UUID1>/<UUID2>_0x283d218b0` but `Failed to create safeguard location for file` because `The file “<UUID2>” doesn’t exist.` (at the source).

---

When I restart the app, the errors are gone. Also, as far as I can tell, all the images *can be displayed*.

Still it bugs me to have that many errors and not understand them. Does anybody understand more than I do?

Comment: I don’t know what causes this, but I see it on macOS 10.15 and 11.3 even when using external storage without CloudKit. I can reproduce it intermittently in unit tests. I’ve not yet detected any problems accessing the data, but the errors are certainly spooky.

Comment: Did you find the source of these console errors? I am in a similar situation and they just popped at me from a test device when I installed an updated build. No idea about the cause (or effect, if any), but I too save images as binary data.

Comment: No, I haven't, sorry